# How to add domain restriction to REST CAS

Tags: java, servlet-filters, cas, jasig

In our project we're using jasig CAS solution. Recently we've added RESTful interface. To be 100% secure I want to provide restriction on URLs. Only trusted URLs should be able to send requests to this API.

What is the best approach, does CAS support such requirement? So far I thought about:

- Some firewall/server configuration
- Create a Filter with lists of trusted URLs

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually, domain restriction is hard to maintenance in real-business-world. So better way is to choose different way to allow access for trusted services. Preferred way is for example: digital signature.

Answer (score 1):

it depends on your requirement, suppose your server has more than one application and you want restriction on selected application then go through

```
Create a Filter with lists of trusted URLs
```

Or 
You are sure that there is always only and only one application is available in your server then go through

```
Some firewall/server configuration
```

Comment: I'm sure that it will be only one domain, but a few applications. I thought that CAS has built-in mechanism to support this, but unfortunately doesn't have any. the Filter has cons: Managing whole list of all environments: test-env, prod-env etc.